# jquery not working with chrome,all other browsers work fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, opera

if you go to my site: http://www.ftvshow.com/

you will see 3 ajax in front page,two of them top of the site and one in side bar, all of them works in firefox,opera,internet explorer, but none of them work with chrome!

as you can see the carousels are not clickable and the tab widget on the sidebar is messed up.
I tried removing plugins,that didn't work,

can you help me?

Comment: works for me ... chrome 31 win 7

Comment: works fine to me also. try to update your chrome. mine: 29.0.1547.66 m

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: i did nothing happend

Comment: my chrome is up to date :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is your problem but Chrome seems to have an issue with cache-ing ajax requests in some recent versions. Setting jQuery's ajax option 'cache' to false may resolve the issue.